# jquery loading external html with plugin

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, external, flexslider

I am using jquery's ajax loading function to load an external html. The external html is using jquery and a jquery plugin called flexslider (an image gallery). The documentation says to load the flexslider with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            slideshow: true, slideshowSpeed: 7000, animationDuration: 600, pauseOnAction: true, pauseOnHover: false});
    });
</script>
```

When I call this it does not work. I tried doing this on the parent page but it did not seem to work either. I also made sure to load the external html before I initialized flexslider. Is there another event I should use on the parent page instead of

```
$(window).load(function(){});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use `$(window).load(function(){});`

use `$(document).ready(function(){});`

OR

```
window.onload = mymethod();
function mymethod()
{
   alert('onload occured')
}
```

​
instead

[see the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nawazhi/Pgbg6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

When you loads html page with ajax, then after loading you can bind the **flexslider** on ajax complete ( like a callback ) instead of doing it in $(window).load() or $(window).ready().

```
.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )
```

Reffer to http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/faq/.

Basically, the problem boils down to the hook which jquery/javascript uses to attach functions to events. Many of the normal hooks you would expect to use - e.g. jQuery(document).ready(...) - won't trigger after an ajax load.

So you have to take the same code that triggers on page load and make sure it also gets triggered *after* the ajax load.

Caveat: I haven't actually ever done this myself, so I can't give code examples I'm afraid. I'm just working on something which might need this functionality myself, so thought I'd share what I found in my exploration.